# Combine checkbox and button in same CSS horitonzal menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

Menu items for the Zoom portions I need them to function as a button click. The Test1-4 I need to function like a checkbox. The Zoom to buttons are working correctly. The Test1-4 are not working properly

```
<body>
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li class='active'><a href='index.html'><span>Home</span></a></li>
    <li><a title='Zoom to U.S' input type='button' name='US' onclick='US();'><span>Zoom to U.S.</span></a></li>
    <li><a title='Zoom to Canada' input type='button' name='Canada' onclick='Canada();'><span>Zoom to Canada</span></a></li>
    <li><a title='Zoom to Mexico' input type='button' name='Mexico' onclick='Mexico();'><span>Zoom to Mexico</span></a></li>    
    <li><a title='Test 1 KML' input type='checkbox' id='kml-Test1-check' name='kml-Test1-check' onclick="toggleKml('Test1');"><span>Test 1 KML</span></a></li>
    <li><a title='Test 2 KML' input type='checkbox' id='kml-Test2-check' name='kml-Test2-check' onclick="toggleKml('Test2');"><span>Test 2 KML</span></a></li>
    <li><a title='Test 3 KML' input type='checkbox' id='kml-Test3-check' name='kml-Test3-check' onclick="toggleKml('Test3');"><span>Test 3 KML</span></a></li>
    <li><a title='Test 4 KML' input type='checkbox' id='kml-Test4-check' name='kml-Test4-check' onclick="toggleKml('Test4');"><span>Test 4 KML</span></a></li>
    <li><a title='Additional KMLs'input type='button' name='AKML' onclick='open_win();'><span>Additional KMLs</span></a></li>
    <li><a title='Remove all KMLs on the screen'input type='button' name='RKML' onclick='killKML();'><span>Remove All KMLs</span></a></li>
    <li class='last'><a title="Contact"><span>Contact</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
```

---

```
#cssmenu {
  border: none;
  border: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font: 67.5% 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Bitstream Vera Sans', 'Trebuchet Unicode MS', 'Lucida Grande', Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: auto;
}
#cssmenu ul {
  background: #333333;
  height: 35px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#cssmenu li {
  float: left;
  padding: 0px;
}
#cssmenu li a {
  background: #333333 url('images/seperator.png') bottom right no-repeat;
  display: block;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 35px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px 25px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  color: #cccccc;
}
#cssmenu ul ul a {
  color: #cccccc;
}
#cssmenu li > a:hover,
#cssmenu ul li:hover > a {
  background: #2580a2 url('images/hover.png') bottom center no-repeat;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#cssmenu li ul {
  background: #333333;
  display: none;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 225px;
  z-index: 200;
  /*top:1em;
    /*left:0;*/

}
#cssmenu li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
#cssmenu li li {
  background: url('images/sub_sep.png') bottom left no-repeat;
  display: block;
  float: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 225px;
}
#cssmenu li:hover li a {
  background: none;
}
#cssmenu li ul a {
  display: block;
  height: 35px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-style: normal;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px 10px 0px 15px;
  text-align: left;
}
#cssmenu li ul a:hover,
#cssmenu li ul li:hover > a {
  background: #2580a2 url('images/hover_sub.png') center left no-repeat;
  border: 0px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#cssmenu p {
  clear: left;
}
```

Comment: If there's a problem with your JS you should provide also this part of the code and define better what "is not working properly" means. Also you could provide a jsfiddle to make easier to help you

Comment: *"checkbox portion will not work load the item"* what checkbox?

Comment: Your HTML is in correct, instead of `<a title='Zoom to U.S' input` use `<a title='Zoom to U.S' ><input`

Comment: Seriously, who up-voted this? It is neither clear nor useful.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/deaconf19/7E8Ea/embedded/result/

Comment: So, what doesn't work in that fiddle? Looks fine to me.

Comment: Test1-4 need to look like a button but function as a checkbox to load and unload KML files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your HTML is in correct, instead of

```
<li><a title='Zoom to U.S' input type='button' name='US' onclick='US();'><span>Zoom to U.S.</span></a></li>
```

Use

```
<li><a title='Zoom to U.S'><input type='button' name='US' onclick='US();'/><span>Zoom to U.S.</span></a></li>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5Zu8m/)

Comment: This fixed the problem, however a checkbox is displayed. I would like for it to look like a button. I tried adding the hide input in CSS, however this breaks the checkbox. Any idea?